# Spring Data JPA Query method duplicates objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to retrieve a list of objects using a query method in the following way:

```
@Entity
public class Cancellation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cancellation", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Schedule> schedules = new HashSet<Schedule>();

}

@Entity
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private Date date;

    @NotNull
    private Time time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Cancellation cancellation;

}



public interface CancellationRepository extends CrudRepository<Cancellation, 
Integer> {  

    List<Cancellation> findBySchedulesDateGreaterThanEqual(Date date);

}
```

The problem is that the query is returning an object well and the rest returns empty, when only one Cancellation object should be returned within the list. The number of objects that are returned matches the number of Schedules in DB.

[image: In the image in single object Cancelled not empty is the first]

In the image in single object Cancelled not empty is the first.

**SOLUTION**

According to the suggestion of @JBNizet I have changed my method to:

```
List<Cancellation> findDistinctCancellationBySchedulesDateGreaterThanEqual(Date date);
```

Now works like a charm

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is `distinct`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Thanks!! @JBNizet changing my method to findDistinctCancellationBySchedulesDateGreaterThanEqual solved my problem